# useState doesn't change the boolean value in first instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've made a button to change the value of a state when it is clicked.
But the value of doesn't change when the button is clicked for the first time. After the first click the value does starts changing. I am learning React and I am a beginner so this might be a no brainer but can you please help me.

`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Button() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(false);

  function handleClick() {
    setTheme(!theme);
    console.log(theme);
  }

  return <button onClick={handleClick}> Click me </button>;
}
```

`

Link to sandbox where I was practicing this.
https://codesandbox.io/s/button-sanbox-x4q2i2?file=/src/button.js:0-263

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: `useState` is asynchronous. The changes to your state will only be reflected on the next render of the component. Check the link above.

Answer (score -1):

Change:

```
function handleClick() {
  setTheme(!theme);
}
```

to:

```
function handleClick() {
  setTheme(currentTheme => !currentTheme);
}
```

The problem has to do with [stale closures](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/).

Comment: there is nothing with stale closures. No async operations, no `useCallback` with wrong/incomplete/empty dep list. The issue is just because OP expects state variable to be updated immediately, not on the next re-render

Comment: I did what you asked for. Still isnt giving me the desired result

Answer (score -2):

Just try it:

```
return <button onClick={() => handleClick()}> Click me </button>;
```

Comment: It doesn't works in my sandbox. Still gives the same result

Comment: `onClick={() => handleClick()}` and `onClick={handleClick}` are equal so far `handleClick` does not expect any argument and does not return anything(although it's not like `onClick` handler would process return value, even if there was any)